# Geb/Spock - Login failures after first feature test runs during automation

Tags: selenium, ui-automation, spock, geb

We have recently started using Geb/Spock for our automation and I've run into an issue that doesn't make any sort of sense to me at all.  This will be a bit complicated to explain but I will try my best.

My company uses an in-house custom built login service for all of our applications at the company.  What our tests do is use the setupSpec() to launch the URL to our application and then in the setup() I have a login method:

setupSpec():

```
def setupSpec() {
    page = waitFor(10) { to LoginPage }
}
```

navigateToLogin():

```
    def navigateToLogin(){
    page = at LoginPage
    login(page)
    waitFor { at HomePage }
}
```

login():

```
    static def login(LoginPage page){
    page.username.value("username")
    page.password.value("password")
    page.signInButton.click()
}
```

Then it runs the feature test, and then our cleanup() method clicks a logout button and waits for the browser to return to the login page.  This concludes the test and starts the next test.  However, this is where the issue starts.

When the second test enters the login method and enter the username and password and clicks Sign In, our login service gives me a message that says "We are experiencing difficulties" which is a message we usually get when the login service is having issues of their own.  But the kicker is the login service is NOT having issues.  This error occurs after the first feature test every single time.  If I open browsers of my own and run my tests manually back to back, I have no issues, so I do not believe our login service is the issue here.

What I'm baffled by is this:  if I run my tests in Debug mode and pause it when it gets back to the login page after logging out and then I type in the credentials on my own I can login without any issues.  However if I leave the automation running and type in the username and password quickly before the test fails (there is a 5 second waitFor) the test fails with the "techincal difficulties" error.

So typing in the same credentials the automation uses WHILE automation is running = login failures.  Typing in the same credentials when automation is NOT RUNNING or is PAUSED = success.

This leads me to believe the automation is holding on to SOMETHING and passing it incorrectly.  The problem is I have no idea what.  We have tried clearing cookies on each logout without results.  We used @Stepwise on our tests is this actually worked, we were NOT getting login failures.  However we cannot use @Stepwise because we don't want the tests to stop running on the first failure.  So @Stepwise is doing something differently that we want to happen minus the stopping on first run.

We currently having it working with a "workaround", where we put the `page = waitFor(10) { to LoginPage }` from setupSpec() into the navigateToLogin() method so it looks like:

```
    def navigateToLogin(){
    page = waitFor(10) { to LoginPage }
    login(page)
    waitFor { at HomePage }
}
```

Essentially all we are doing is changing the `at` and the `to`.  When we have the 'to' then what happens is when we logout and we are on the login page, it basically re-enters the app URL and refreshes the page.  This works, for reasons I do not understand.  I'd like to remove the refresh if possible because it's wasted time.  For a short amount of tests the wasted time is trivial, but for running the full suite it is not trivial.

Does anyone have any insight on what could be happening?

Comment: Is the logout async? What happens if you add a sleep for 1 second after logout.

Comment: Please share more information. Those fragments make it hard to see what is going on. BTW, you should not have to assign values to `page` because Geb should take care of doing that whenever you call `to` or `at`. One more thing: In your helper method, if `at` fails, no error will be thrown because there is no `assert` for it. Implicit assertions only work in feature or fixture methods.

Comment: One more thought: Relying on the previous test to initialise test resources the way you expect them makes tests interdependent. You should never rely on that but make sure your test fixtures are set up correctly each time you start a feature method - especially because you cannot rely on any order of method execution.

Comment: @kriegaex from the docs it looks like at is asserted http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#at-checking

Comment: I think you are right in this matter. It has been long ago since I actually wrote my last Geb test. My bad, I did not know that implicit assertions are active for "at checkers" even when `at(..)` ist called from a helper method. I still think that my other statements about MCVE and inter-dependent feature methods hold.

Comment: @kriegaex I also understand the assigning and passing the `page` object. Although there is no example in the Geb examples, it makes it easier to see the object scope when using an IDE.

Comment: @Royg we added hard sleeps for the sake of testing exactly your thought and it did not make any difference. kriegaex, Royg has pretty much answered all of your comments for me.  The at is doing an assert, and the reason we put page. on every line is because the IDE gives us the scope and we can u so the auto complete features.  We still have not figured out the issue but we are working around it by just not logging out now.  I'm still rather confused but I'm picking my battles.

Comment: @jcattau have you tries `waitFor(10) { at LoginPage }` and not `to`?